# Issues exporting "Person or Group" type column to XML - SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, xml

We are trying to export SharePoint List to XML by building an url of the format - `http://{0}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={1}&XMLDATA=TRUE`

```
{0} – The URL to your site.  This could be the root web or a child site.
{1} – The GUID for your list.
```

(As explained here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/05/01/getting-xml-data-from-a-sharepoint-list-the-easy-way.aspx)

This works as long as there are no columns in the SharePoint list which is of "People or Group" type. Once a column of that type is included in the list, accessing the URL will repeatedly ask for user credentials and won't generate XML even after providing the right credentials.

Is there a known issue with XML export of "People or Groups" column in SharePoint 2010. What is the work-around?

Comment: I couldn't replicate this. Check fiddler for the response or error message that you're getting when accessing the URL.

Comment: This seems to work for me too. I'm assuming you are already authenticated to the site. Are you saying it prompts you again for credentials? By the way, I am using SP2013 so maybe not a fair comparison?